# file lock existence check on remote host

Tags: linux, c, glusterfs, pthreads

I want to check the existence of file lock on a file in gluster file system. So that I can see from any host that whether file lock is held by any process (remote or local) on file in gluster file system.

For Example:
I have two host: *h1* and *h2*, both with RHEL 7.2. I have one application on host *h1* which has acquired the file lock on a file in gluster file system using `pthread_rwlock_wrlock` API. After sometimes I poweroff host *h1*.

Now from *h2* I am using `pthread_rwlock_trywrlock` to see whether any lock is held on this file or not. this retuning me `EBUSY` till 30 minutes of poweroff of *h1*(its looking as if application from *h1* has still held lock on it). After around 30 minutes `pthread_rwlock_trywrlock` returning `0`.

Is there any way I can quickly check that a file in gluster is held by any any process or not?

Answer (score 0):

After tuning below gluster volumes parameter it worked.

```
network.frame-timeout 30
network.ping-timeout 5
server.keepalive-time 5
server.keepalive-interval 2
server.keepalive-count 2
server.tcp-user-timeout 5
```

After above parameter tuning of gluster volumes. I am seeing application on remote host able to detact lock existence on a lock file in glusterfs in within 10 sec on VM poweroff.